# Recordset field values return null from SQL server with varchar(MAX) data type

Tags: sql-server-2008, excel, excel-2010, vba

I have an SQL 2008 server, in the server is a table that has a column with a data type of varchar(MAX). I am trying to import certain columns from this table into Excel 2010 using ADO. Here is an example of the code I am using:

```
Dim con As Object
Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

cmd.CommandText = "SELECT dbo.(Table Name).Name From dbo.(Table)"
cmd.CommandType = 1
con.open
cmd.ActiveConnection = con
Dim rst as Object
set rst = cmd.Execute

ActiveSheet.cells(targetRange.Row, targetRange.Column).CopyFromRecordset rst
```

The code executes just fine, however because the column Name is set to varchar(MAX) none of the names show up in the worksheet. I know this because I made a copy of the SQL server and changed the data type for the column to varchar(1024) and it works the way it should.

I also tried placing the data in the recordset into the spreadsheet manually but with no luck. So the problem is I can not change the real SQL server.

Is there a command that I can add to the Select statement or a cast that I can use that will convert the varchar(MAX) to a data type that Excel can use, or is there something else I can do so that the data is not null when I read it in?

I have been looking into this problem for a day now with some threads coming close but they are talking about using select on the SQL server with a cast which doesn't work in this case, or in some other program, which doesn't help.

Comment: Did you try to cast the type? `SELECT CAST(dbo.(Table Name).Name AS VARCHAR(1024)) FROM dbo.(Table)`

Comment: I did try it but I was using it wrong, Thank you for that everything works.  Your a real life saver : )

Comment: This is poor advice, the provider being used is the problem. update the connection string to use the correct provider and `VARCHAR(MAX)` will work just fine. The reason this *appears* to work is that SQL Server casts it to a data type the older provider knows how to handle.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ADO apparently doesn't handle `VARCHAR(MAX)` properly (or how you might expect), something about returning a zero column size as its not defined like it would be for `VARCHAR(n)`.

You answered your own question, as you just needed to cast your column to something with a defined length!

```
CAST(column AS type)
```

or in your case

```
SELECT CAST(dbo.(Table Name).Name AS VARCHAR(1024)) FROM dbo.(Table)
```

Comment: It's got nothing to do with ADODB handling the data type properly it is simply the provider being used doesn't know how to handle `VARCHAR(MAX)` because the provider pre-dates the data type, update the connection string to use the correct provider.

Comment: While it might not be the perfect solution, it did fix the issue. @Lankymart Why not add an answer detailing the better solution?