# Select long text from SQL using Excel VBA ADO returns garbage characters

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, adodb, parameterized-query

I can't figure out how to retrieve long text (>8kb) from a SQL Server field using an ADODB connection through Excel VBA. My method returns a garbage string.

I can successfully upload a field with >8kb data length using a parameterized query as in the following code:

```vb
Public Sub TestLongParamUploadQuery()
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
    Dim param As ADODB.Parameter
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

    Query = "INSERT INTO MYTABLE ([Long_Text], [Table_Index]) VALUES (?, ?);"
    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    conn.ConnectionString = connStr
    On Error GoTo connerror
    conn.Open
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    With cmd
        .ActiveConnection = conn
        .CommandText = Query
        .CommandType = adCmdText
        Set Pm = .CreateParameter("long_text", adLongVarWChar, adParamInput, 20000)
        Pm.Value = Replace("THIS IS A REALLY LONG TEXT STRING " & Space(8000) & "THIS IS A REALLY LONG TEXT STRING", " ", ".")
        .Parameters.Append Pm

        Set Pm = .CreateParameter("table_index", adVarChar, adParamInput, 32)
        Pm.Value = "MYFAKERECORD"
        .Parameters.Append Pm
        Set rs = .Execute
    End With
connerror:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Msg = "Error # " & str(Err.Number) & " was generated by " _
        & Err.Source & Chr(13) & "Error Line: " & Erl & Chr(13) & Err.Description
        MsgBox Msg, , "Error", Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
    End If
    conn.Close
End Sub
```

But when I attempt to retrieve the data via a `SELECT` statement, the data comes back garbled.

```vb
Public Sub TestLongParamDownloadQuery()
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
    Dim param As ADODB.Parameter
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Query = "SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE Table_Index='MYFAKERECORD';"
    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    conn.ConnectionString = connStr
    On Error GoTo connerror
    conn.Open
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    With cmd
        .ActiveConnection = conn
        .CommandText = Query
        .CommandType = adCmdText
    End With

    Set rs = cmd.Execute()

    Do Until rs.EOF = True
        For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
            If Not IsNull(rs.Fields.Item(i)) Then
                Debug.Print ("field '" & rs.Fields(i).Name & "' length: " & Len(rs.Fields.Item(i)) & "; value: '" & rs.Fields.Item(i) & "'")
            End If
        Next
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop

connerror:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Msg = "Error # " & str(Err.Number) & " was generated by " _
        & Err.Source & Chr(13) & "Error Line: " & Erl & Chr(13) & Err.Description
        MsgBox Msg, , "Error", Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
    End If
    conn.Close
End Sub
```

The data is successfully making it into the database.  I'm able to open and see it in SQL Server Management Studio.

However. The `Debug.Print` output from my download looks like the following

```
field 'Long_Text' length: 8067; value: '                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  MYFAKERECORD                                                                                                                             ?                  ?%0??       ?%0??       ?                  ?                  ?                  ?                  ?                                                                                                                                                                            






                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     '
field 'Table_Index' length: 12; value: 'MYFAKERECORD'
```

Note that the length appears to be correct. It's not merely an issue in printing in the immediate window of the Excel VBA IDE. When I write the data to an excel cell via the macro, the cell contains '``' after upload.

I've tried the upload with the parameter for Unicode `adLongVarWChar` and plaintext `adLongVarChar`. Both appear to place data correctly in the database. Both come back as broken text from the `select` statement.

**What is the appropriate way to download and interrogate long text via adodb?**

**EDIT** I did find [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15418712/recordset-field-values-return-null-from-sql-server-with-varcharmax-data-type) which notes a fundamental limitation that ADO cannot interpret `nvarchar(max)` type.  The proposed solution of CAST'ing the variable to nvarchar(20000) will not work for me because the upward limit for CAST is 8000 characters.  How can I transfer data from a field GREATER than 8kb to Excel VBA?

Comment: `cast( as text)`.

Comment: Thanks @GSerg!  That's perfect.  2 hours of googling and I did not come across that thread.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This answer was drawn from the post [What are the limits for ADO data types?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6905003/11683)

The solution as is to:

1. Cast the desired fields as `text`.
2. Retrieve the actual data from the record set using `string = rs.Fields(0).GetChunk(rs.Fields(0).ActualSize)`

Incorporating into my code it looks like:

```
Public Sub TestLongParamDownloadQuery()
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
    Dim param As ADODB.Parameter
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Query = "SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE Table_Index='MYFAKERECORD';"
    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    conn.ConnectionString = connStr
    On Error GoTo connerror
    conn.Open
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    With cmd
        .ActiveConnection = conn
        .CommandText = Query
        .CommandType = adCmdText
    End With

    Set rs = cmd.Execute()

    Do Until rs.EOF = True
        For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
            If Not IsNull(rs.Fields.Item(i)) Then
                If rs.Fields.Item(i).Name = "Long_Text" Then
                    Debug.Print(rs.Fields(i).GetChunk(rs.Fields(i).ActualSize))
                End If
                Debug.Print ("field '" & rs.Fields(i).Name & "' length: " & Len(rs.Fields.Item(i)) & "; value: '" & rs.Fields.Item(i) & "'")
            End If
        Next
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop

connerror:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Msg = "Error # " & str(Err.Number) & " was generated by " _
        & Err.Source & Chr(13) & "Error Line: " & Erl & Chr(13) & Err.Description
        MsgBox Msg, , "Error", Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
    End If
    conn.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: You don't seem to be using cast as text in that code.